# Sequentially remove vector elements

Tags: r, vector, seq

I want to replicate a vector with one value within this vector is missing (sequentially).

For example, my vector is

```
value <- 1:7
```

First, the series is without 1, second without 2, and so on. In the end, the series is in one vector.

The intended output looks like

```
2 3 4 5 6 7 1 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 5 6 7 1 2 3 4 6 7 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Is there any smart way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can certainly do it as a one-liner but I am not sure it qualifies as smart. For example:

```
x <- 1:7
do.call("c", lapply(as.list(-1:-length(x)), function(a)x[a]))
```

This simple uses `lapply` to create a list of copies of `x` with each of its entries deleted, and then concatenates them using `c`. The `do.call` function applies its first argument (a function) to its second argument (a list of arguments to the function).

Answer (score 3):

You could use the diagonal matrix to set up a logical vector, using it to remove the appropriate values.

```
n <- 7

rep(1:n, n)[!diag(n)]
#  [1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 5 6 7 1 2 3 4 6 7 1 2 3 4 5
# [36] 7 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 0):

For fun, it's also possible to just use `rep`:

```
> n <- 7
> rep(1:n, n)[rep(c(FALSE, rep(TRUE, n)), length.out=n^2)]
[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 5 6 7 1 2 3 4 6 7 1 2 3 4 5 7 1 2
[39] 3 4 5 6
```

But `lapply` is cleaner, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do:

```
n <- 7
rep(seq(n), n)[-seq(1,n*n,n+1)]

#[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 5 6 7 1 2 3 4 6 7 1 2 3 4 5 7 1 2 3 4 5 6
```